# Type Narrowing Array Using Array.prototype.filter()

Tags: typescript

Support I have:

```js
type MapItem {
    name: string,
    lng?: number
    lat?: number
}

function foo(data: MapItem[]): void {
    ...
}
```

Then, if I attempt to do

```
function foo(data: MapItem[]): void {
    data
        .filter(item => !!item.lng && !!item.lat)
        .map(item => {
            ... // `item` is still of type `MapItem`
            ... // `lng` and `lng` are still `number | undefined`
         })
         ... // Some other array operations like reduce(), filter(), map(), etc.
}
```

What would be the correct way if I want to do type narrowing (such as ensuring that `lng` and `lat` are not `undefined`) in such array chaining?

[TS playground for reference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghmAksCBbKBeKBvAUFAqAOzlQgC4oBnYAJwEsiBzAGn0IBtmB+SogV1QAjCLTaEoHOMF7FBIsbgC+uVQDN+RAMbB6AeyJQ1evQAoAJtLiV4SFKgDaAXQCUlAG5765nOwKXgOD8JKAA6NXoOFFpTentMAD4oAEJkuLRQriYoADIclLT7TOkXYIlQ1ARY+IwkvBCGqHT0AHoWqAADZo6mqmpdDg4oPTUoUEhO22Q0DrLG5uLgFiairKg2zqyeuCIfDq2oOFpoGkihjoFhUSgAHyhNcwgIoghzWcaCJVKP9faAZT0ZGGwAAFtcjrQ4CBhpBIboDH0OPQANbQY7mfhaCCmFzLCJRUQ45aVMBEqAQYBaULKIA)

Comment: You need to pass a type guard function to `.filter()`. You can use `data.filter((data): data is {lng: number; lat: number} & MapItem => !!item.lng && !!item.lat` or [extract that out if you think it becomes too long](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=12&ssc=10&pln=12&pc=34#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghmAksCBbKBvAsAKCvqAOzlQgC4oBnYAJwEtCBzAGlwKgBsmB+CwgV1QAjCDTYEOcYLyKCRYnAF9cuACYQAxpJrQNAe0LUoqqXArwkKVAG0AugG4VOUJFgJkaAGpwOdVVABeTC5GPjlRe04pMOFRRSgAMjdLNCcAM35CDWA6Ayg6Sm9fVQAKOitzdysASgpytHzKZI9UIr9McR1gfhpCKABCfvrUADoQxKTB4bGpXGUcE2A4cRG0ug4UGjLCnz9qldQEMqtAgD5MKHF8fUNgKAAPQPyrMaYoAGooAGZLpWqgA)

Comment: So the automatic type inference that we have in if-else statements is not applicable with `.filter`. Is that intentional or is it a bug? Is using a type guard the only way to get past this?

Comment: OK, I think I got it. I will stick with the type guard solution.

Comment: Yes, TS will not automatically do type narrowing with a filter. It needs to know that's what you're doing with the array